# Cell has text and number, but I need to count both

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel database formatted in a calendar style for employee holidays and wages.

Sarah works the same shift pattern every week, so in the cell that relates to Monday, I have "8", for 8 hours worked. If Sarah books a holiday on that Monday, I want to still display the 8 to show that she will be paid for 8 hours, but I also want to put an H in the same cell to indicate that she is taking it as holiday.

Outside of the calendar, in another column, I have used the SUM function to calculate the total amount of hours worked for that month.

In another column next to that, I have a COUNTIF for the number of times the letter 'H' appears, which will then deplete her holiday allowance for that year.

The problem is, if I enter "8 H" into one cell, the SUM function doesn't work, and removes the 8 from her total amount of monthly hours meaning she won't be paid, but should be, but it DOES count the H.

Is there a formula to count the number and the letter in one cell and show them in the relevant columns without omitting data?

Conditional formatting doesn't seem to work on fill colour alone so I'm stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: It would become rather messy to either split the `8 H` entry, or to modify the formulae to deal with the combined values. I do not recommend such a solution. Maybe you could consider an extra column beside the hours column, with the meaning of *special treatment*. It would be quite simple to apply different rules based on that column. In the future you might need other special treatment codes in addition to the `H` for holidays. Perhaps something like `S` for sickleave or `C` for childcare etc.

Comment: Why not just sum her holiday? Shudders... Do you really log working hours?

Comment: Can you post the formulae you're currently using so we can see what you're starting with?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write `H` in Cell `A5` `Sarah` in `A6` & `John` 
  in `A7`.
- Enter this formula in Cell `B6` to **Count 
  Holidays** & fill down.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((LEN(B2:G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:G2,$A$5,"")))/LEN($A$5))
  ```
- **To Count General hours** write this formula 
  in cell `D6` & fill down.

  ```
   =Sum(B2:G2)
  ```
- Write this formula in Cell `C6` to **calculate 
  Holiday's Hrs.** & fill down.

  ```
    =SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(B2:G2,$A$5," "))-D6
  ```
- Enter this formula in Cell `E6` to **calculate 
  total hours** & fill down.

  ```
   =C6+D6
  ```

*You get the complete illustration of Holidays, along with General, Holidays & Total Hours.*

**Note:**

- Since your *holidays are paid* so that in Cell 
  `E6` I've summed **Hol.Hrs with Gen. Hrs**, 
  *otherwise you may calculate wages on Gen. 
  Hrs.*
- *Adjust cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution:
Double click in the cell you need the total Holiday Hours and paste:

**=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(G2,A2:E5)),VALUE(LEFT(A2:E5,FIND(G2,A2:E5)-1)),0))**

then press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to create this array formula.
Modify the formula acording to your ranges.

[image: IMG #1]

Then sum the holiday hours and the normal hours.

[image]