# Excel 2019 Mac: filtering by letters then sum of the number in the same cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a grid of two letter initials with a number beside them. I would like to list all the two letter initials with a total of the number that is beside them.

Example TI 4, SJ 6, ER 2, TI 2.5, SJ 4

RESULT

- TI 6.5
- SJ 10
- ER 2

For context it is peoples initials and number of hours worked

I’ve tried sumif, but can’t get it to do the required

Note: am aware it would be easier to split columns, but this is the data format desired to work with for ease of entry

Comment: When you say "grid",  what do you mean? To me it looks like you have a single cell with a long text string such as [TI 4, SJ 6, ER 2, TI 2.5, SJ 4].  Or do they land in different columns and rows?

Comment: They land in different rows and columns the cell break denoted by the commas.  
I’ve been trying to use the last solution here https://superuser.com/questions/1366250/cell-has-text-and-number-but-i-need-to-count-both with right vs left, but only getting ‘#value’

Comment: *"They land in different rows and columns the cell break denoted by the commas."* Which comma splits into different columns, and which into different rows?  Can't you lay it out to display as it does on your worksheet?